# Openlayers layer hide javascript menu

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript

I have java-script menu that is getting behind openlayers OSM layer (only after it loads).
I've tried giving z-index:9999 to the menu div but it didn't work.
Any idea ?
[image]

Comment: can we see your app?

Comment: Is the map div wrapped in the same parent as the menu?

Comment: U2ros - Yes it does.
Aragon - I'm not sure I can show the app because of NDA. If I won't solve it soon I'll have to do something about it.

Comment: Attached example :
http://www.hadav.com/ZIndexTest/Assets/ShowAssetsTable.aspx

Ignore the error message, its just example :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened the example and found that your menu div id=ctl00__MenuV_MultiLevelMenun0Items has a fixed z-index = 1.

Update it to a value like 1100 so it will be on top of other things.
Your menu code is pushing z-index back to 1. Fix this.